# Gerar PDF em Golang

Tags: golang, pdf

A dificuldade se encontra na criação da variável "err" na qual não consigo desenvolver, consegui perceber que o erro se dá pela fonte que o arquivo está tentando usar e minha máquina não possui o arquivo dessa font. Como é um arquivo do GitHub, não fui eu que fiz, peguei ele pronto para analisar a estrutura, vou disponibilizar o link.
https://github.com/signintech/gopdf

```
package main    
import (
    "log"    
    "github.com/signintech/gopdf"
)

func main() {    
    pdf := gopdf.GoPdf{}
    pdf.Start(gopdf.Config{PageSize: *gopdf.PageSizeA4})
    pdf.AddPage()
    //err := pdf.AddTTFFont("wts11", "../ttf/wts11.ttf")
    err := pdf.
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = pdf.SetFont("wts11", "", 14)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }
    pdf.Cell(nil, "您好")
    pdf.WritePdf("hello.pdf")    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

É possível compilar este exemplo, segue os passos que eu fiz para executar com sucesso:

Criei um projeto com o comando:

```
$ go mod init example.com/x
```

Criar um projeto com a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

```
.
├── _main.go
├── _ttf
    └── wts11.ttf
```

O arquivo `wts11.ttf` pode ser baixado no repositório que contém a lib gopdf. [`Ref`](https://github.com/oneplus1000/gopdfsample/blob/master/ttf/wts11.ttf). Abrir em um browser e baixar o arquivo (aprox. 10.1 MB).

Após fazer o download colocar o arquivo baixado na hierarquia de pastas descrita acima.

Agora será possível executar o programa:

***main.go***

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/signintech/gopdf"
)

func main() {
    pdf := gopdf.GoPdf{}
    pdf.Start(gopdf.Config{PageSize: *gopdf.PageSizeA4})
    pdf.AddPage()
    err := pdf.AddTTFFont("wts11", "ttf/wts11.ttf")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = pdf.SetFont("wts11", "", 14)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }
    pdf.Cell(nil, "您好")
    pdf.WritePdf("hello.pdf")
}
```

Supondo que está na raiz do diretório do projeto e seguiu as instruções acima:

```
$ go run main.go
```

Após a execução com sucesso deve haver um arquivo `hello.pdf` na raiz do diretório do projeto.